# It says System.String[] when i tries to output the value

Tags: c#

When I try to output the appointment.Categories value it says: **System.String[]**

But it output fine all the other values to plain text.

I have tried ToString(), but that did not seems to work.

```
myText.InnerHtml += "subject::" + appointment.Subject + "\n";
myText.InnerHtml += "starttime::" + appointment.StartTime + "\n";
myText.InnerHtml += "endtime::" + appointment.EndTime + "\n";
myText.InnerHtml += "categori::" + appointment.Categories + "\n";
```

These are the values there are from Microsoft
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635637(v=exchg.80)

How can I output the System.String to plaintext?

Comment: `.Categories` **is not a string**.

Comment: Categories is a collection of Objects, you need to iterate over the collection and print out each category in it. A foreach loop would be perfect for this.

Answer (score 6):

Categories is not a string, but an array of strings, you need to print each string one at a time.

Replace

```
myText.InnerHtml += "categori::" + appointment.Categories + "\n";
```

with

```
foreach(var category in appointment.Categories)
{
    myText.InnerHtml += "categori::" + category  + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> How can i output the System.String to plaintext?

It's *not* a `System.String`. It's an *array* of strings. How do you *want* to convert the array of strings to a single one? For example, you could use:

```
string joined = string.Join(",", appointment.Categories);
```

Comment: How is String.join() implemented? Is it just a syntactic sugar of foreach loop or the implementation is different. Please let us know.

Comment: @Sandeep: It's a method call. How could that be syntactic sugar? I don't know the implementation offhand, but obviously it will have to iterate...

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems `appointment.Categories` is a **string array** and **not** a string. You could use the following:

```
myText.InnerHtml += "categori::" + String.Join(", ", appointment.Categories) + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.String[]` or a string array does not override the `ToString` method by default. That's why it prints the type name when concatinating with other strings. Use [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to get a user friendly string representation.

```
string categories = String.Join(", ", appointment.Categories)
```

`categories` contains now "Cat1, Cat2, Cat3" for an array `["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the array

```
myText.InnerHtml += string.Join("categori::", appointment.Categories) + "\n";
```